# Is there a way to add a hover effect on featured products?

Tags: css, hover

I have "featured products" on my front page, is there a way to give them a hover effect?
thank you

Comment: If you search your exact tags on Google... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Answer (score 1):

:|

Use this :

```
    .yourclass-name:hover{

     Your Codes 

    }
```